# Angular ui-router prevent state trigger inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have a directive `clickable-tag` for which i am passing my `data` as the tag's name (`tag.tag`):

```
<a class="item item-avatar"
   ui-sref="nebula.questionData({questionId: question.id})"
   ng-repeat="question in questionsData.questions">
    <img src="{{question.user.profile_photo || '../img/avatar.jpg'}}">
    <h2 class="question-title">{{question.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{question.description}}</p>
    <div class="question-tags-list" ng-repeat="tag in question.tags" clickable-tag data="{{tag.tag}}">
        <button type="submit" class="tag">{{tag.tag}}</button>
    </div>
</a>
```

The directive `clickable-tag` is inside a `ui-sref` (on the outer `a` tag). Inside the directive, I want the outer `ui-sref` to be prevented and instead the user should be directed to another state (the one i am specifying in the directive below).

```
.directive("clickableTag", function($state) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      data: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('click', function(ev) {
        console.log('scope.tagName: ', scope.tagName);
        if (scope.data) {
          $state.go('nebula.tagData', {tagName: scope.data});
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

The problem is that only the `resolve` of the state specified inside the directive runs. The view which is actually rendered is of the state specified by the outer `ui-sref`.

Any solutions as to how to prevent the outer `ui-sref` from being triggered. and instead trigger a state change as specified inside the directive ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Note:** I have already tried `preventDefault()`, `stopPropagation()`, `return false` inside my directive.

Comment: I suppose the clickableTag directive is loaded correctly, right? If it is the case you could listen on $stateChangeStart inside the directive and prevent transition there.

Comment: @FlorianTopf I am already listening to the `$stateChangeStart` inside `app.run`. Not sure about how to use it inside a directive though ?

Comment: you can inject `$rootScope` to the directive and then listen to the `$stateChangeStart` event. You can listen to this event as often as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `ng-repeat` outside and above the `<a>` tag and move the close of the `<a>` tag above the button.

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questionsData.questions">

   <a class="item item-avatar"
        ui-sref="nebula.questionData({questionId: question.id})">

       <img src="{{question.user.profile_photo || '../img/avatar.jpg'}}">
       <h2 class="question-title">{{question.title}}</h2>
       <p>{{question.description}}</p>
   </a>  <!--Put close of A tag here --->

   <div class="question-tags-list" ng-repeat="tag in question.tags"
             ng-click="$state.go('nebula.tagData', {tagName: tag.tag})">

       <button type="submit" class="tag">{{tag.tag}}</button>

   </div>
</div>
```

For more information see the [AngularJS ng-click API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Comment: I am not sure about it. Though the main problem is to prevent the outer `ui-sref` from firing, which doesn't seem to be addressed by your proposed solution.

Comment: Edited it for your problem.